# Complex numbers calculator

Tags: python, complex-numbers, idle-processing

So, if I type (4*9j**2) into the console, it returns (-324+0j) Is there any way to re-create this with code, basically, take input and simplify it as if you just typed it into the console (j acts as the imaginary number i)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in function [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

```
>>> 4*9j**2
(-324+0j)
>>> equation = "4*9j**2"
>>> eval(equation)
(-324+0j)
```